# Docker image with a single file Akka.net app and the Petabridge command line?

Tags: docker, .net-core, akka.net

I'm writing an Akka.net hosted application that I intend to host in docker. I want to minimize the footprint so I'm making this a single file executable.  But I also want to include the Petabridge command line. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

[Petabridge App Template](https://github.com/petabridge/Petabridge.App) maybe what you are looking for.

You can either look at how it is done with that repo or create a new project using that template.

Please let me know if this answers your question!

**EDIT**
I have pasted below a reference from the repo to help you achieve this:
https://github.com/petabridge/Petabridge.App/blob/e86e40c5b7cbb0faf4228f109ce03bed3b647c4d/src/Petabridge.App/Dockerfile#L13-L32

Comment: thanks for your response and I apologize for the late reply. I only just now saw this. I think this will only work if I use the mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime image.  I want to use mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps - which doesn't have any of the actual framework components I think it will need to run the command line.